# Typing Greek letters etc. in plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to type Greek letters and the Angstrom symbol in labels of axes in a plot. So for example

```
fig.gca().set_xlabel("$wavelength\, (Angstrom)$")
fig.gca().set_ylabel("$lambda$")
```

except that I actually want "Angstrom" and "lambda" replaced by actual symbols. How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not only can you add raw strings to matplotlib but you can also specify the font in matplotlibrc or locally with:

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font', **{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

This would change your serif latex font. You can also specify the sans-serif Helvetica like so

```
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
```

Other options are `cursive` and `monospace` with their respective font names.
Your label would then be

```
fig.gca().set_xlabel(r'wavelength $5000 \AA$')
```

If the font doesn't supply an Angstrom symbol you can try using `\mathring{A}`

Comment: The Angstrom is not satisfactory with this option, because it appear italic. The $\text{\AA}$ which works in latex does seem to work here. Also there should an option which preserved the font used for these characters. How to do that?

Comment: You can use the letter Å instead of a dedicated Ångström symbol (Å), since very few fonts contain the latter, and most ot them use identical glyphs for both, anyway. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#Symbol_for_.C3.A5ngstr.C3.B6m

Answer (score 112):

You need to make the strings [raw](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and use [latex](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#text-rendering-with-latex):

```
fig.gca().set_ylabel(r'$\lambda$')
```

As of matplotlib 2.0 the default font [supports most western alphabets](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#fonts) and can simple do

```
ax.set_xlabel('λ')
```

with unicode.

Answer (score 19):

If you want tho have a normal string infront of the greek letter make sure that you have the right order:

```
plt.ylabel(r'Microstrain [$\mu \epsilon$]')
```

Answer (score 15):

Python 3.x:
small greek letters are coded from 945 to 969
so,alpha is `chr(945)`, omega is `chr(969)`
so just type

```
print(chr(945))
```

the list of small greek letters in a list:

```
greek_letterz=[chr(code) for code in range(945,970)]

print(greek_letterz)
```

And now, alpha is  `greek_letterz[0]`, beta is `greek_letterz[1]`, a.s.o

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use the literal characters?

```
fig.gca().set_xlabel("wavelength, (Å)")
fig.gca().set_ylabel("λ")
```

You might have to add this to the file if you are using python 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals  # or use u"unicode strings"
```

It might be easier to define constants for characters that are not easy to type on your keyboard.

```
ANGSTROM, LAMDBA = "Åλ"
```

Then you can reuse them elsewhere.

```
fig.gca().set_xlabel("wavelength, (%s)" % ANGSTROM)
fig.gca().set_ylabel(LAMBDA)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
print('Omega: \u03A9') # Ω
print('Lamda: \u03BB') # λ
```

Visit the Website for more symbols
[More Symbols](https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/unicode-characters-in-python.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should display the Angstrom (nonitalicized).

```
ax.set_xlabel("$\mathrm{\AA}$",labelpad=2, fontsize=10,fontweight='bold')
```