# How do I write a capital Greek "delta" as a string in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, unicode, symbols

I am looking for this character: `Δ` which I need for a legend item in matplotlib. Python 3.x features a `str` type that contains Unicode characters, but I couldn't find any valuable information about how to do it in Python 2.7.

```
x = range(10)
y = [5] * 10
z = [y[i] - x[i] for i in xrange(10)]

plt.plot(x,z,label='Δ x,y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: See the answer with the most votes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338550/typing-greek-letters-etc-in-python-plots): `label=r'$\Delta$x,y'`

Comment: Thanks berna! I already found that answer, but when I try it, I get an error (German): "The command "latex" is either mis-spelled or could not be found" (possibly an error from the command shell?). And later (English): "RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string: 'lp' "

Comment: Yes, you would need latex installed for this shortcut to work. But you can see how to pick a new font with the symbol on the question I pointed (or the great answer by @Diziet ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although @berna1111's comment is correct, you don't need to use LaTeX format to get a ∆ character.
In python 2, you need to specify that a string is unicode by using the `u''` construct ([see doc here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)). E.g.:

```
plt.plot(x,z,label=u'Δ x,y')
```

Comment: Thanks, Diziet! Your suggestion suppresses the error, but the symbol cannot be displayed in the plot. There is just the blank rectangle.

Comment: you probably use a font that does not have the ∆ character. Try to play around with fonts in rcParams (see http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) or try something like `plt.legend(prop={'family':'Times New Roman'})`