# Missing polish characters in matplotlib.pyplot labels (regardless of using UTF-8)

Tags: python, matplotlib, character-encoding

I'm trying to create a histogram using `matplotlib` library.

I set encoding to UTF-8, but some of the polish characters (not all, only some) are missing.
I've tried to play around `encode` and `decode`, but without success.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sampleData
data=[[ 0.13837092,  0.14755699,  0.17719047,  0.1998352 ],
       [ 0.19318216,  0.15863521,  0.17136143,  0.18979461]]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, facecolor='green') 

# I've tried also adding: .encode('UTF8') and .decode('UTF8'), but without success
plt.xlabel("Wartości ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.ylabel("Prawdopodobieństwo ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.title("Tytuł ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("sampleHist.png")
plt.clf()
```

Result:
[image: sampleHist.png - some polish chatacters are not visible]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338550/typing-greek-letters-etc-in-python-plots

Comment: The encoding is fine. But you are using a font that doesn't contain those characters. The duplicate question explains how to change the font used in matlabplot.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments - yes it was a matter of using different font.
Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set font which contains polish characters:
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')


#sampleData
data=[[ 0.13837092,  0.14755699,  0.17719047,  0.1998352 ],
       [ 0.19318216,  0.15863521,  0.17136143,  0.18979461]]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, facecolor='green') 

plt.xlabel(u"Wartości ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.ylabel(u"Prawdopodobieństwo ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.title(u"Tytuł ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.")
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("sampleHist.png")
plt.clf()
```

[image: sampleHist.png]