# Matplotlib writing '±' in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following this [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338569/3083243), I can use raw string and latex to get μ+σ from `r'$\mu$' + '+' + r'$\sigma$'`. How can I write **μ ± σ** as a legend in a matplotlib plot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The text is `r'$\mu \pm \sigma$'`.

Answer (score 3):

The plus minus sign in LaTeX is \pm. `r'$\mu \pm \sigma$'` should work.